# What's the syntax for a no-op Promise in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

Often I find myself writing `beforeSave` and `afterSave` using promises in this form:

```
beforeSavePromise: function (request) {

    var recipe = request.object;

    var promises = [
        doFooIfNeeded(recipe),
        doBarIfNeeded(recipe),
        doQuuxIfNeeded(recipe)
    ];

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises)
},
```

Each of these are conditional actions that perform an action only if a particular field or fields are dirty. So for example, `doFooIfNeeded` might look something like:

```
if (recipe.dirty('imageFile')) {
    return /* some Promise that updates thumbnails of this image */; 
} else {
    return Parse.Promise.as();  // The no-op Promise. Do nothing!
}
```

My question is, is `Parse.Promise.as()` really the no-op `Promise`? or is `new Parse.Promise()` more correct?

Comment: What do you want the returned promise to be resolved with?

Comment: null, or unit, I suppose. Javascript doesn't have the concept of unit so null is as close as it comes.
`Parse.Promise.as()` is the same as `Parse.Promise.as(null)` isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all "dirty" outcomes contributing a resolved promise to the aggregation, you can choose for each "clean" outcome to contribute in any of the following ways :

1. not to put anything in the array,
2. put a value in the array,
3. put a resolved promise in the array,
4. put a rejected promise in the array.

(1), (2) and (3) will guarantee that the aggregated promise resolves regardless of the clean/dirty outomes (except some unpredicted error).

(4) will cause the aggregared promise to resolve only if all outcomes are "dirty", or to reject as soon as any one "clean" outcome arises.

Realistically, the choice is between (2) and (4), depending on how you want the aggregated promise to behave. (1) would complicate the aggregation process, and (3) would be unnecessarily expensive.

It would seem appropriate for the aggregated promise to resolve when everything is either already "clean" or has been cleaned up, therefore I would suggest (2), in which case your `foo()`/`bar()`/`quux()` functions could be written as follows :

```
function foo() {
    return recipe.dirty('imageFile') ? updates_thumbnails() : true; // doesn't have to be `true` or even truthy - could be almost anything except a rejected promise. 
}
```

And aggregate the outcomes as in the question :

```
$.when([ foo(recipe), bar(recipe), quux(recipe) ]).then(function() {
    //all thumbnails were successfully updated.
}).fail(function() {
    //an unexpected error occurred in foo(), bar() or quux().
});
```

Comment: Thanks roamer-1888 that is a very concise and complete answer. I guess this was a question to establish what is thought of as 'idiomatic' Parse Cloud Code.

Using `true` might optimize on the performance but sadly it could also appear confusing. I think I'll stick to `Parse.Promise.as()` for clarity.

Comment: For clarity, you could use a meaningful string eg `"already clean"` in place of `true`. Even a string is more efficient than a Parse promise.

Answer (score 1):

`Parse.Promise.as()` will technically give you a Promise with its state set to `resolved`. When you return this Promise, its callback will be triggered successfully. You can supply a value as an argument which basically triggers the callback with that value. According to the Parse guide on [Promise creation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises-creating-promises), `new Parse.Promise()` creates a Promise that its states is *neither* set to `resolved` nor `failed`. This gives you the flexibility to mange its state manually as you wish.

Comment: Okay so there's no more elegant way to write my conditional `fooIfNeeded()` function then is there?

Comment: Well you do not need to put a resolved Promise in that array. You just need to wait for on an array of Promises to finish if you have pending actions. So when a field is not dirty just do nothing and skip to the next one.

Comment: You mean, it's legal for me to just return null from `fooIfNeeded()` instead of a resolved `Parse.Promise`?

Comment: No I meant update promises array if only your function has to perform something

Comment: ... The whole point is that the array contains CONDITIONAL actions. I couldn't tell you at edit-time whether a function does something or not @MoNazemi -_-